# I'm wondering if there exists a real positive function whose infimum on every open interval is zero

Tags: real-analysis

I'm wondering if there exists a function $f\colon \Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, such that $f(x)> 0$, for all $x$, but $\inf f(a, b) =0$, for all open interval $(a, b)$.

And what happens if I replace the condition $\inf f(a, b)=0$ with $\inf f[(a, b)\cap (\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q)]=0$?

Comment: is $f$ continuous?

Comment: There are functions $f$ with the stronger condition $f(a,b)=(0,\infty)$ for all $a<b$.

Answer (score 6):

Consider $f(x) = 1$ whenever $x$ is irrational, and $f(x) = |\frac{1}{q}|$ whenever $x = \frac{p}{q}$ is a fraction in lowest terms.

---

But considering that you're asking about topology, I'd guess that you want continuity to be a requirement. In this case, the answer is no.

Comment: Continuity is not a requirement.  Nice and simple solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let $T_0 = \mathbb{Z}$, and given $T_n$, let $T_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \mathbb{Z} \setminus T_n$. Define $f(x) = 1_{(\cup_{n=0}^\infty T_n)^c} (x) + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} 1_{T_n} (x) $.

Comment: @T.Bongers: You are right, I typed too quickly.

Comment: Nice solution. I'll remove my obsolete comment.

Comment: @T.Bongers: Still have a few bugs...

Comment: I assume that you mean to define it to be some fixed positive number on the numbers which aren't dyadic rationals.

Comment: @T.Bongers: Yup, thanks again. I was aiming for a one-liner!

Comment: @T.Bongers: But now its uglier than I intended :-(...

Comment: It's still one line... But life is hard ;)

Comment: In other words $f((2k+1)/2^n)=1/2^n$ for every integers $n$ and $k$, and $f(x)=1$ for every $x$ not dyadic.

Comment: @Did: Yes indeed, but I have a preoccupation with indicator functions.